# GitHub live link doesn't show on GitHub pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I just uploaded my app into the repository but the link that shows "your app is life at ..." doesn't get displayed in the pages section. Also, the `gh-pages` selector under the select branch dropdown menu doesn't display either.

- I created a repository then in the terminal I typed:

1. git init
2. git add .
3. 

```
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/camoqq/myapp.git
git push -u origin main
```

4. npm install gh-pages --save-dev
5. in the package j.son i
   added the homepage, predeploy and deploy
6. in terminal
   -git add .
   -git commit -m "any'
   -git push
   -npm run deploy

I have done it many times with smaller apps and it works all the time but this project has many pages and it shows the code part of my app but I can't see the live version of it.

Does anybody know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

> `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`

Then add your github page URL as the "homepage" in your `package.json`:

```json
"homepage": "https://GIT_NAME.github.io/REPO_NAME",
```

Also, add these scripts to your `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
   "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
   // [...]
}
```

Then you should be able to run `npm run deploy` which will deploy your site under a **gh-pages** branch with all the static files. Make sure in the repo settings that the deploy branch is set to gh-pages.

More info can be found [**here**](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages).

Comment: i did these steps already but still didnt work

Comment: It isn't a private repository, is it? Can you link the repo?

Comment: its public. im sorry , i am new to github, do you mean a link to the source code?